# What is angle in CATransform3DRotate method?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, catransform3d

I am working on a application showing my heading and bearing to the location I want to go. I want to display a arrow direction to the direction user should have his heading to rich the desire location. There is nothing to get worry about this. What I want to do is I have degrees.. 0-360.

When I pass these degrees to the angle in bellow method this react strange. The Image get totate more than once.
I tried to get radians from the degrees and than tried but no success.

All I want is I have float value range between 0-360 and I wanted to rotate my image only once a 369 degree rotation.

I have passed radians too. For converting degrees to radians I used:

```
float radian = degrees * M_PI / 180
```

But this is also having same issue. All I want is image show work like a compass for all 360 degrees.

How to get angle for this method:

```
CATransform3DRotate (CATransform3D t, CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z)'
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass radians there. For example, this will rotate image on 180 degrees:

```
switcher.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

if you have problems with converting degrees to radians, you can use following macroses:

```
#define DegreesToRadians(degrees) (degrees * M_PI / 180)
#define RadiansToDegrees(radians) (radians * 180 / M_PI)
```

Comment: @Nekto : can you please help me? my device restarted when I rotate CATransform. I post question  http://stackoverflow.com/q/43488520/2671883